# how to disable Magento Cache for slider

Tags: php, magento, caching, enterprise

I have been struggling with cache storage in magento enterprise edition. problem is in the magento home page slider, each time if a user visit the website,the home page banners should be shuffled randomly.

For that i am shuffling banners with their banner ids, i am using shuffle(bannerids) in app/code/core/Enterprise/Banner/Model/Resource/Banner.php page

with the above code, the banners were shuffling but when i click the same region repeatedly the same shuffle order is repeating and it was due to cache storage.

Please let me know how can i disable cache for banners block i.e home page sliders block
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should include some code from your attempts so far. What guides have you followed from your prior research on StackOverflow and Google?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to "hole-punch" the banner block, so that it isn't cached as part of FPC.

I would recommend looking at alternative FPC caching modules such as https://gordonlesti.com/projects/lestifpc/, which allow you to specify dynamic blocks.